# How to remove duplicate integers from an array AND return duplicate integers in a new array

Tags: arrays, function, loops, duplicates

Having a difficult time removing duplicate integers from an array and returning duplicate removed integers in a new array. I tried using a loop on the test but I didn't know how to push removed integers into a new array I think.

function dedupe(num){

}

Comment: So to clarify, you want to find all elements in array 1 which are present more then once, remove them from array 1, and add them to array 2, is that right?

Can you add an example of what your function should do.  For example, if given the array `[x, x, y, z, y, x]`, what should your function return?  What will the first array look like afterwards?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it will solve your problem

```
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,5,4,2];
let dublicateElement = [];

const findDublicate = (array) => {
const count = {};
 for(item of array){
  if(!count[item]){
   count[item] = 1;
  }else{
   dublicateElement.push(item);
  }
 }
}

findDublicate(arr)
console.log(dublicateElement)
```